# Tracing keypresses in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code that should run when the respective button is pressed, but nothing happens. Why would this be?

```
def keyReleased(self,event):
    if event.keysym == 'Right':
        self.move('Right')
    elif event.keysym == 'Left':
      direction=  self.move('Left')
    elif event.keysym == 'Up':
        self.move('Up')
    elif event.keysym =='Down':
        self.move('Down')
    elif event.keysym =='Escape':
        self._root.destroy()
```

Comment: No, I wasn't aware you had to do this

Comment: So i should do something like `root.bind('Right', self.keyReleased)`?

Comment: The code that is run doesn't currently work, as i'm still trying to work that out. But the buttons in general wouldn't even run the code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind key event to the callback.

For example:

```
from Tkinter import * # Python 3.x: from tkinter import *

def hello(e=None):
    print('Hello')

root = Tk()
Button(root, text='say hello', command=hello).pack()
root.bind('<Escape>', lambda e: root.quit())
root.bind('h', hello)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Brief sidenote: 
On of the changes in Python 3.x is that the import is lowercase:
`from tkinter import *`

Answer (score 1):

bind_all is one way to do it .  Note that arrow keys are under the "special key" category for the code below.

```
    try:
        import Tkinter as tk     ## Python 2.x
    except ImportError:   
        import tkinter as tk     ## Python 3.x

    def key_in(event):
        ##shows key or tk code for the key
        if event.keysym == 'Escape':
            root.quit()
        if event.char == event.keysym:
            # normal number and letter characters
            print'Normal Key', event.char
        elif len(event.char) == 1:
            # charcters like []/.,><#$ also Return and ctrl/key
            print( 'Punctuation Key %r (%r)' % (event.keysym, event.char) )
        else:
            # f1 to f12, shift keys, caps lock, Home, End, Delete ...
            print( 'Special Key %r' % event.keysym )

    root = tk.Tk()
    tk.Label(root, text="Press a key (Escape key to exit):" ).grid()

    ent=tk.Entry(root)
    ent.bind_all('<Key>', key_in)  # <==================
    ent.focus_set()

    root.mainloop()
```

But if you only want the arrow keys then you can bind each one to a function

```
    def arrow_down(event):
        print "arrow down"

    def arrow_up(event):
        print "arrow up"

    root = tk.Tk()
    tk.Label(root, text="Press a key (Escape key to exit):" ).grid()

    root.bind('<Down>', arrow_down)
    root.bind('<Up>', arrow_up)

    root.mainloop()
```